# Un-ignore a specific bin directory

Tags: git, visual-studio, gitignore, team-explorer

I have a large repository containing many VS dll projects and a couple of web folders.  I want to blanket ignore all the bin and obj folders generated by all the those dll projects.  However I do not want to ignore the bin folder in the web folders.  Here is a much simplified secenario, a list of folders may look like this:

```
/DllProject1
/DllProject1/someInnerNamespace
/DllProject1/properties
/DllProject1/bin
/DllProject1/bin/debug
/DllProject1/obj/
/DllProject1/obj/debug

/DllProject2
/DllProject2/someInnerNamespace
/DllProject2/properties
/DllProject2/bin
/DllProject2/bin/debug
/DllProject2/obj/
/DllProject2/obj/debug

/Web
/Web/App_Code
/Web/assets
/Web/clientBin
/Web/bin
/Web/someModule
```

Bearing in mind that in the real world there are many more dll projects that may be found it various levels of folder structure.  I would like to use a .gitignore that would look something like this:

```
bin
obj
!/Web/bin
```

This "should" ignore all bin and obj folders where ever they appear in the rep, but "should" explicitly un-ignore the /Web/bin folder.  However that doesn't appear to work, the Web/bin folder disappears anyway.

Comment: I will stand by what I said below, namely that the build artifacts should not be where the source code is.  But maybe a guru like @VonC can give you the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The `.gitignore` example you wrote works perfectly fine as you specified it, I just tested it. However I would add trailing slashes to only match directories, not files.

Is your problem maybe that you have no file in `/Web/bin` and are not aware that Git does not track folders? Git tracks content that happens to be stored in files, but it does not track files or folders, thus you cannot add an empty folder to a Git repository.

Comment: Thanks.  The bin folders definitely have content.  I wonder if this is specific to VS and Team Explorer.

Comment: I wouldn't expect so. Try how plain Git commandline client behaves. If it behaves differently, open a bug entry for the tool that handles it wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert with writing `.gitignore` files, but I see several problems with your current approach.  First, why are your object and binary files inside the repository in the first place?  They should not be there, nor should any of your build artifacts.  Instead, build into a location *outside* where your source code is being stored.

With regard to your `.gitignore` file, the correct order is to exclude a parent folder but then include the subfolder as an exception.  So, if you wanted to exclude the `web` folder but include its `bin` subfolder, you would do something like this:

```
/web/*
!/web/bin/
```

I'm not sure if using a blanket ignore on `bin` will give you the results you want.  But as I said, you should probably move your build artifacts outside of the `.git` parent folder.

Comment: Thanks for you response.  The goal here is a "it just works" environment that doesn't require developers to remember a set of rules to get work done.  A VS dll project by default creates bin and obj folders under the project directory and to me that kind of makes sense.  So I don't agree with your assertion about where temporary "build artifacts" ought to be,  Also your suggestion will ignore everything in the web folder except the bin folder which clearly can't be desirable.  I think I kept too much detail out of my question.

Comment: Typically manually ignoring build artifacts isn't a general use case, at least not for the languages/projects I have had exposure to.  Maybe your situation is different.  I'm just trying to give you useful information.